# Are questions like "is this the best way to do X" off-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I found this recent question: [New to SQL Server 2012, improve monthly change query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547208/new-to-sql-server-2012-improve-monthly-change-query).

Normally questions like "is this the best way to [insert something here]? are off-topic, and normally are closed pretty quickly.

Questions like the one I found are increasingly being asked, they're normally closed.

Question: If the initial question asks for ***suggestions or improvements*** to the code, is it off-topic?

Comment: Someone's already suggested this on the question, but, yeah, isn't that _exactly_ what Code Review is for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the most abstract general sense, they are not off topic. However, practically, they are.

Here's why.

These questions are generally written in this form:

> Here's my code:
>
> ```
> //snip of code. Or if we aren't lucky, dozens of lines of code
> ```
>
> Is there a way I can do this better?

The problem is that this question is not searchable.  No one looking on Google would have anything to go on to find this question.  Even if they did find this question, it wouldn't be useful to them because there is no actual problem statement; the code itself is generally not abstracted out, nor does it use common terminology that would be useful to others.

These sorts of questions could be on topic if they met the following criteria:

1. They spell out an actual problem. "I'm trying to vary behavior based on a property of a child class"
2. They are searchable.  "What's wrong with this code?" Is not searchable. "How can I make this code better" is not searchable.
3. They do their best to abstract out the code into a general problem code -- instead of being about their classes and their objects, it should work in general for a class that meets certain criteria.

This is important because it's harder to view design pattern questions when you have to fight both with the design pattern they're trying to implement, and their naming convention for their code (As well as the names themselves).

Most likely, once they meet the above criteria, they're probably better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), as long as the OP [meets the requirements that the Code Review site has set up for questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).